# Icon Variables for Ext Icons

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

In Ext message box we used to provide variables for buttons like `Ext.Msg.Button` icon. Is it possible to do the same in our Ext MVC Model of Application?

Comment: The question is not very clear. Can you explain it more?

Comment: When you want t o give icons for Message Box we will use Ext.Msg.Help , like wise is it possible to give such common names for our custom icons rendered to buttons too , so that in future we can handle changes easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by including a resource in your project and then providing the mapping to that icon (how you do this depends upon the architecture of your application); reading the documentation will help you discern how to do that: both the documentation [example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.window.MessageBox) and then digging a bit into the `icon` [config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.window.MessageBox-cfg-icon).:

> Path to image for an icon.

That's all that `Ext.Message.Help` is: a path.

The `Ext.button.Button` also has the `icon` [configuration](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-icon), just follow the example in the Ext.window.MessageBox documentation linked above.

Here's the code from the doc.s:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
    title:'Save Changes?',
    message: 'You are closing a tab that has unsaved changes. Would you like to save your changes?',
    buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNOCANCEL,
    icon: Path.to.icon // Here, supply the resource path
    // ....
});
```

You can also do in-line configuration of buttons through Ext JS if wanting to take advantage of the `Ext.Msg.show({});` functionality.